# How to Move Excel Values inside a Datagridview?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

First I will explain what I'm trying to do. Previously I made a macro that moves the values from column J to column H.

[image]

As you can see the values are move to so they can match with the same value in column G.

[image]

This is the macro I am using to get this:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rwg = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns("J"), .Cells(rwg, "G").Value2)) Then
                rwj = Application.Match(.Cells(rwg, "G").Value2, .Columns("J"), 0)
                .Cells(rwg, "H") = .Cells(rwj, "J").Value2
                .Cells(rwj, "J").ClearContents
            End If
        Next rwg
    End With
```

Now I will like to get this done by clicking in the match button in this Winform I made:

[image]

Is it possible?

I'm storing the data in data tables:

```
string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox_Path.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);

            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Importe, Conciliación, Retiros, Depositos from [" + textBox_Sheet.Text + "$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: how are you storing the data?

Comment: What have you tried (in C# I mean)? BTW, do you know that VB.NET can do the same than C# and its syntax is much more similar to VBA/Excel macros?

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes, it is possible (can be done in quite a few different ways). But we are not here to write code as per your requirements. You should take a look at the help section to understand the way in which you should ask/answer (e.g., asking specific questions about issues which are relevant to others, making some effort by your own, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

for above question you should read the each excel row by colunm
and the add this value to Detatable

1st Read the Excel File

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // get first sheet
                    Excel.Range currentFind = null;
                    Excel.Range xlRange = null;
                    xlRange = xlSheet.UsedRange;
```

2nd after satrt reading each data row by row

```
 var rowno = 1;//your Row No
    var Colno = 1;//Column no
long LastRow = xlRange.Rows.Count;
    for (int j = 0; j < lastCols; j++)
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < lastrowss; j++)
                 {
                  CellValue = Convert.ToString(((Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[rows,Colno]).Value2); 
            dr = dtTemp.NewRow();
            dr[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(CellValue);
           dtTemp.Rows.Add(dr); 
           rows++;
         }
    Col++
    }
    Dgsource=dtTemp
```

Hope This will help you
dnt